# Sine wave one dimensional or two dimensional?

Tags: geometry

As the topic says,what is sine wave 1D or 2D
The sine wave is shown in figure:

[Sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqWbm.gif)

Till now I had the understanding that a wave plotted on a plane(XY) is two dimensional.

Please clear the concept if I am wrong

Comment: You should edit your post to add details about what you mean by *dimension*. Because depending on the context, you can explain that the sine wave is 1-dimensional or is 2-dimensional. So what are you working on that requires you to think about the dimension of a sine curve?

Comment: It would not be possible to tell - the graph only gives the amplitude in (presumably) one dimension.

Comment: If time does not count as a dimension, then your wave is 1-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we analyze a wave by either showing

1. displacement-position graph of particular time; or
2. displacement-time graph at particular position.

Sometimes we use a wave function to describe the displacement for whole space ($x$ in one dimension) at all time.

For a sine wave moving to the right, we have
$$\phi(x,t)=A\sin \left( \frac{t}{T}-\frac{x}{\lambda} \right)$$

[image]

Comment: So what is your conclusion?

Comment: Your diagram actually is the displacement-time graph for particular particle.   You need further information for the nature of the wave.  May be it's cylindrical or spherical wave.